# How to run php & java script code at the backend of Joomla article or module.. advise

Tags: joomla

i am confused how to attach my php and javascript code  in with their modules etc.. can anyone recommend me with  tutroial so that i can understand ..

I tried making static pages but could find the way to  write php code.. all extension their i found out are about inserting the php code as in  to the pages but not executing .. *banging head on wall*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Sourcerer plugin (http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/5051) in order to be able to code php/javascript straight into articles and have it execute on the page.

It works really well - is a simple installation and runs well.

If you're having issue with the code disappearing on you, read through the documentation - you can change the tags to [[ instead of < and it will save the code in the article for you and it works really well.

Best plugin I've used for executing JS/PHP inside articles/modules.

Comment: is it possible to include an external php file with sourcerer? Jumi plugin used to be able to do this. Coding in the article box is such a pain.

Comment: I believe so.  It allows almost all PHP coding if I recall correctly - so if you can do it in PHP, you can include that into the article without issue; this should include linking to external files.

Also, I agree - coding in the article box is a pain!  I wish they included a way to write pure PHP by default, that would be such a huge plus!